# SwiftUI UINavigationBar does not ignore the top safe area. How to get rid of empty space on the top?

Tags: swiftui, uinavigationbar, swiftui-navigationview, uinavigationbarappearance

[image]

Code I used to create an example of this navigation bar:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    init() {
        let defaultAppearance = UINavigationBarAppearance()
        defaultAppearance.configureWithOpaqueBackground()
        defaultAppearance.backgroundColor = .red

        UINavigationBar.appearance().standardAppearance = defaultAppearance
        UINavigationBar.appearance().setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), for: .default)
    }

    var body: some View {
        ParentView()
    }
}

struct ParentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                NavigationLink(destination: DetailView()) {
                    Text("Tap here")
                }
            }
            .navigationBarTitle("", displayMode: .inline)
            .navigationBarHidden(true)
            .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
        }
    }
}

struct DetailView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Detail View")
        }
        .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
   }
}
```

It doesn't matter where I'm putting .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all) it doesn't work. Is there another way to tell Navigation Bar to ignore the safe area?

If it's not the safe area problem, then I need to make the whole navigation bar to have the same height of UINavigationBarContentView displayed in UI Hierarchy:
[image]

Comment: Due to you have set navigation bar color safe area not showing. It actually ignoring. You have to change the navigation bar Appearance coloe.

Comment: What I need is to get rid of empty space on the top.

Comment: Which space are you talking about? Please mark in image

Comment: If it's not the safe area problem, then I need to make the whole navigation bar to have the same height of UINavigationBarContentView displayed in UI Hierarchy. I updated the post with a screenshot.

Comment: No just search change the color of status bar with white navigation

Comment: I don't need to change any colors. What I need is to have navigation bar to look roughly like this: https://pasteboard.co/K69OaxW.png

Answer (score 0):

I'm unsure if you still need help with this but in **iOS 16.0+** you can instead apply `.ignoresSafeArea()` in all the places you have invoked `edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)`. Then add the following code to your initializer in order to apply a custom background color to the entire navigation bar, including the safe area:

```
let defaultAppearance = UINavigationBarAppearance()
defaultAppearance.configureWithDefaultBackground()
defaultAppearance.backgroundColor = .red
UINavigationBar.appearance().scrollEdgeAppearance = defaultAppearance
```